# Mapping range variable EF Core to List for automapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have built a linq query that joins across multiple entities. I would like to use one of the range variables from the joins as `IEnumerable` parameter to pass to auto mapper map method. Problem I'm having is the range variable is the entity type and not a list type which I would need to successfully map to a generic `List<Dto>` collection.

Here's the example:

```
var test = await (from cpm in dbContext.Cars
                  join ad in dbContext.CarModels
                          on new { ManufactureId = cpm.ManufactureId, CarId = cpm.CarId } equals new { ManufactureId = ad.ManufactureId, CarId = ad.CarId }
                  into agd
                  from ads in agd.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select _mapper.Map<List<CarModelsDto>>(agd)).ToListAsync();
```

Here's the error:

> 'variable 'agd' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DBContext.Data.Edm.Entities.CarModels]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Comment: I don't think you can straightway use the Automapper to map into another model in IQueryable. But, you need to materialize the query first (execute the query) then only using AutoMapper for mapping DTO. Meanwhile, I think you should return `ads` instead of `agd`.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Not think that you can directly use the Automapper in `IQueryable`. But you need to materialize the query first (execute the query and get the result), then only use Automapper to map into DTO.

While in your query should return `ads` rather than `agd`. From your query, you are returning the records from the right table from LEFT JOIN, which possibly the record is `null`.

Your code should be looked as below:

```cs
var test = await (from cpm in dbContext.Cars
                  join ad in dbContext.CarModels
                  on new { ManufactureId = cpm.ManufactureId, CarId = cpm.CarId } equals new { ManufactureId = ad.ManufactureId, CarId = ad.CarId }
                  into agd
                  from ads in agd.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select ads).ToListAsync();

var result = _mapper.Map<List<CarModelsDto>>(test);
```